# VHDL code to find square root of number?

Tags: vhdl

Is there is any in built function or any library that can be included in the design to find square root of a number?

Comment: You need to try it on your own then may be put up your doubts (wherever you get stuck).

Comment: `y := math_real.sqrt(x)` gives you the square root for `real` type... and if that is not what you want, please show what you tried so far...

Comment: @MortenZilmer this will help. Can I directly put this line in my code?

Comment: Please see answer; but note that it won't synthesize as I write in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me.

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

entity squart is port( 
clock      : in std_logic;  
data_in    : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
data_out   : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)); end squart;

architecture behaviour of squart is

signal part_done  : std_logic := '0';
signal part_count : integer := 3; 
signal result     : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "00000"; 
signal partialq   : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := "000000";

begin   
    part_done_1: process(clock, data_in, part_done)  
    begin
        if(clock'event and clock='1')then
            if(part_done='0')then
                if(part_count>=0)then
                    partialq(1 downto 0)  <= data_in((part_count*2)+ 1 downto part_count*2);
                    part_done <= '1';    else
                    data_out <= result(3 downto 0);    
                end if;    
                part_count <= part_count - 1;
                elsif(part_done='1')then
                    if((result(3 downto 0) & "01") <= partialq)then
                        result   <= result(3 downto 0) & '1';
                        partialq(5 downto 2) <= partialq(3 downto 0) - (result(1 downto 0)&"01");    
                    else 
                        result   <= result(3 downto 0) & '0';
                        partialq(5 downto 2) <= partialq(3 downto 0);                     
                    end if;   
                    part_done  <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;  
        end process;   
    end behaviour;
```

Answer (score 5):

Restoring square root algorithm is easy to implement on fpga, [wikipedia has an example](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots%23Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29).

FPGA vendors should have cores available, it hides inside the general purpose CORDIC core on Xilinx. They also have square root cores for floating points, if that's what you need.

Comment: Is there no standard function for this? after more than 30 years of fpga?

Comment: You cannot perform sqrt in a single clock cycle with reasonable latency, thus it would be possible to have a standard function that is synthesizable. There is a function that works on real number as part of the VHDL language. I would consider IP cores "standard function" though, and IP Cores for SQRT are readily available.

Answer (score 2):

For non-synthesizable (simulation/test-bench only) operation, square root for `real` can be done with:

```
y := math_real.sqrt(x)
```

For synthesizable operation, see answer from Jonathan Drolet.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity SQRT is
    Generic ( b  : natural range 4 to 32 := 16 ); 
    Port ( value  : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end SQRT;

architecture Behave of SQRT is
begin
   process (value)
   variable vop  : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   variable vres : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   variable vone : unsigned(b-1 downto 0);  
   begin
      vone := to_unsigned(2**(b-2),b);
      vop  := unsigned(value);
      vres := (others=>'0'); 
      while (vone /= 0) loop
         if (vop >= vres+vone) then
            vop   := vop - (vres+vone);
            vres  := vres/2 + vone;
         else
            vres  := vres/2;
         end if;
         vone := vone/4;
      end loop;
      result <= std_logic_vector(vres(result'range));
   end process;
end;
```